# How can I stop my phone from beeping when I miss a call?

Tags: audio, ringtone, vibration, silent, sound

Even when my ringer is disabled, my phone beeps when I miss a call. This is disruptive, particularly when I'm in class. How can I prevent this beep from occurring?

Comment: What phone are you talking about exactely? Could it be that you get a text message when missing a call?

Comment: @Thomas: I have a HTC 8X. I'm not getting a text message when missing a call (though that should not make a noise either). My vibrate is on, my ringer is off. The phone vibrates while the person is calling, then beeps after they hang up (without me answering).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to assume that you have a Verizon HTC 8X - this is a known issue and you need to wait for Verizon's update:

"After further review this is a known issue with the HTC 8X.  It is under review by HTC and the issue will be addressed with the next software update.  Visit http://vz.to/n5snpq for the latest news on software updates and other device offerings"

Also note that there is a settings on HTC 8X:

At the bottom of the ringtones + sounds setting is a an option to disable All other notifications, this should disable the missed calls alert. However for Verizon the settings will have no effect.

Also read: [Verizon 8X missed call beep](https://community.verizonwireless.com/message/947127)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in Settings -> Accessibility -> Reminder of Messages. When this is on, it will remind every 15 seconds (or max 5 min).